# I can't use yoccaddon in Hybris 5.5.1

Tags: java, sap-commerce-cloud

I am using an Hybris 5.5.1 trial for learning purposes. I want to create a ycommercewebservice addon with yoccaddon like the documentation points, but I don't see that module, just the yaddon.

Iis it the same? I followed the documentation steps but using yaddon insteado of yoccaddon.

I tried with yaddon and after following the documentation and building successfully, my new api resource throws "There is no resource for path /rest/v2/apparel-uk/testing"

My controller has:

```
    package com.test.controllers;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{baseSiteId}/testing")
    public class TestController
    {
        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public String getTesting()
        {
            String testText = "Hello Test";
            return testText;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `@ApiVersion("v2)` or `@ApiVersion("v1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... I am not big familiar with the addon logic of hybris, but what I see here is that you do a request on **/rest/v2/apparel-uk/testing**, but you have only the following Request Mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{baseSiteId}/testing")
```

So the part **/rest/v2/** is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I've got hybris 5.5.1 here and I'm trying to find the yoccaddon myself - I can't. Makes me wonder if it's been deprecated (and if so, why the wiki documentation still refers to it...

Does the API respond if you hit /{baseSiteId}/testing ? I'd suggest adding a web module (with the relevant webfoot configured) in your extensioninfo.xml - e.g.

```
<webmodule jspcompile="false" webroot="/rest/v2"/>
```

This should then mean that your controller will be available on the expected URL.